# htaccess - IP address contains ':' instead of '.'

Tags: .htaccess, virtual-ip-address

A client uses the website 'whatsmyip' website to determine their IP address. What they return is something like ***2001:8003:52ed:4700:d9f:ac11:4f79:xxxx***

Do the same rules apply in creating blocks in the htaccess file?

For example, can I add:
***allow from 2001:8003*** to permit access to all IP's starting with 2001:8003?